# Database schema pattern for grouping transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I am working on an accounting system in which there is a way to revert transactions which are made by mistake.
There are processes which run on invoices which generate transactions.
One process can generate multiple transactions for an invoice. There can be multiple processes which can be run on an invoice.

The schema looks as under:

```
Transactions
========================================================
Id | InvoiceId | InvoiceProcessType | Amount  | CreatedOn
1     1            23                  10.00      Today
2     1            23                  13.00      Today
3     1            23                  17.00      Yesterday
4     1            23                  32.00      Yesterday
```

Now 1 and 2 happened together and 3 and 4 happened together and I want to revert the latter (3,4), what would be a possible solution to group them.

One possible solution is to add a column `ProcessCount` which is incremented on every process.
The new schema would look as under.

```
Transactions
==============================================================================
Id | InvoiceId | InvoiceProcessType | Amount  | CreatedOn     | ProcessCount
1     1            23                  10.00      Today          1 
2     1            23                  13.00      Today          1 
3     1            23                  17.00      Yesterday      2
4     1            23                  32.00      Yesterday      2
```

Is there any other way I can implement this ?
TIA

Comment: How do you know what "every process" is?

Comment: I highly doubt that a value like "Today" for CreatedOn is useful. And I'm going to guess that you actually store a datetime value and not a string. But your goal is impossible without specific knowledge of which process created which rows. There is no alternative without some serious and problematic assumptions. And the column name "ProcessCount" is very misleading IMO - there is no "counting" here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are basing the batching on an arbitrary time frame between the `createdon` date/time values, then you can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  For instance, if two rows are in the same batch if they are within an hour, then:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_createdon > dateadd(hour, -1, createdon) then 0 else 1 end) over 
           (partition by invoiceid order by createdon, id) as processcount
from (select t.*,
             lag(createdon) over (partition by invoiceid order by createdon, id) as prev_createdon
      from transactions t
     ) t;
```

That said, it would seem that your *processing* needs to be enhanced.  Each time the code runs, a row should be inserted into some table (say `processes`).  The id generated from that insertion should be used to insert into `transactions`. That way, you can keep the information about when -- and who and what and so on -- inserted particular transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dense_rank` to identify it as follows:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by InvoiceId  
                         order by CreatedOn desc) as ProcessCount
  from your_table t
```

You can then revert (/delete) as per your requirement, There is no need to explicitly maintain the `ProcessCount` column. It can be derived as per the above query.

Comment: the createdon is not the same for all transactions of a ProcessType, it differs by milliseconds.

Comment: Then use trunc on createdon